# Distance from point to line 3d formula

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, geometry

I am looking for a javascript 3D formula to get the distance from a point to the line. The formula can also be in another programming language.
P is a point, and A & B are points of the line.

```
P=(4,2,1);
A=(1,0,1);
B=(1,2,0);
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905533/find-perpendicular-distance-from-point-to-line-in-3d  The example data in this question is identical to the one posted here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest point `X` to the point `P`on the line (`A`, `V`) is that point, where the line (`X`, `P`) is normal to the line (`A`, `B`).

If a line is defined by two points `A` and `B`, then a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) `D` which gives the direction of the line can be calcualted as follows (Note the length of a unit vector is 1):

```
D = normalize(B-A);
```

For the following formula a point `O` on the line is needed, e.g. `O = A`.

Now the closest point `X` to the point `P` on the line (`O`, `D`) has to be found.

First calculate a vector `V` from `O` to `P`:

```
V = P - O;
```

The distance `d` from `O` to the intersection point (closest point) `X` can be calculated by the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).
In general The dot product of 2 vectors is equal the cosine of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( angle_A_B )
```

[image: dot A B]

Since `D` is a unit vector, the dot product of `V` and `D` is equal the cosine of the angle between the line (`O`, `D`) and the vector `V`, multiplied by the amount (length) of `V`:

```
d = dot(V, D);
```

The intersection point `X`, can be calculated by shifting the point `O` along the line (`D`) by the distance `d`:

```
X = O + D * d;
```

So the formula for the intersection point is:

```
O ... any point on the line
D ... unit vector which points in the direction of the line
P ... the "Point"

X = O + D * dot(P-O, D);
```

[image: intersection line point]

The calculation by points on the line `A`, `B` and the point `P` is:

```
D = normalize(B-A);
X = A + D * dot(P-A, D);
```

The `dot` Product for 3 dimensional cartesian coordinates can be expressed as:

```
dot(A, B) = Ax*Bx + Ay*By + Az*Bz
```

A `normalized` vector (unit vector) can be calculated by:

```
len(A) = sqrt(Ax*Ax + Ay*Ay + Az*Az)
notrmalize(A) = A / len(A)
```

---

In pure Javascript, this can be calculated as follows:

```
var P=[4,2,1];
var A=[1,0,1];
var B=[1,2,0];

var AB    = [B[0]-A[0], B[1]-A[1], B[2]-A[2]];
var lenAB = Math.sqrt(AB[0]*AB[0] + AB[1]*AB[1] + AB[2]*AB[2]);

var D  = [AB[0]/lenAB, AB[1]/lenAB, AB[2]/lenAB];
var AP = [P[0]-A[0], P[1]-A[1], P[2]-A[2]];

var d = D[0]*AP[0] + D[1]*AP[1] + D[2]*AP[2];

var X = [A[0] + d * D[0], A[1] + d * D[1], A[2] + d * D[2]];
```

---

It is easy to this by [Three.js - `Vector3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3), where the operations for the vector arithmetic like `add`, `sub`, `dot` and `normalize` are defined:

```
var P = new THREE.Vector3( 4, 2, 1 );
var A = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 1 );
var B = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 2, 0 );

var D = B.clone().sub( A ).normalize();
var d = P.clone().sub( A ).dot( D );
var X = A.clone().add( D.clone().multiplyScalar( d ) );
```

Comment: Thank you, you have helped to make it more clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

You want to calculate the distance from a point to a line in 3D. three.js has the `Line3` class that will do the calculation for you.

```
var line = new THREE.Line3(); // create once and reuse

var P = new THREE.Vector3(); // ditto
var A = new THREE.Vector3();
var B = new THREE.Vector3();
var C = new THREE.Vector3();

P.set( 4, 2, 1 );
A.set( 1, 0, 1 );
B.set( 1, 2, 0 );

// calculate C, the closest point on the (infinite) line AB
line.set( A, B ).closestPointToPoint( P, false, C ); 

var distance = P.distanceTo( C );

console.log( distance );
```

three.js r.97

Answer (score 0):

```
P=new THREE.Vector3(4,2,1);
A=new THREE.Vector3(1,0,1);
B=new THREE.Vector3(1,2,0);

Normal=B.clone ().sub (A).normalize ()

Distance = Normal.multiplyScalar (P.sub (A).dot (Normal)).add (A).sub (P).length ()
```